# Rails 4 erb Ruby returns nothing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Trying to program in ROR without scaffold. After I open the app with `rails s`, enter every necessary field in `'new'` and enter `'show'` page, `'show'` gives me nothing, like this:

[image: SHOW shows nothing]

And here is my battles/show.html.erb:

```
<% provide(:title, @battle.name) %>
<h1><%= @battle.name %></h1>
<div class="">
  <ul>
    <li><%= @battle.name %></li>
    <li><%= @battle.date %></li>
    <li><%= @battle.location %></li>
    <li><%= @battle.belligerentA %></li>
    <li><%= @battle.belligerentB %></li>
    <li><%= @battle.strengthA %></li>
    <li><%= @battle.strengthB %></li>
    <li><%= @battle.casualtiesA %></li>
    <li><%= @battle.casualtiesB %></li>
    <li><%= @battle.result %></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

In my battle controller, I defined `show` as common:

```
  def show
    @battle = Battle.find(params[:id])
  end
```

Here is my battlecontroller:

```
class BattlesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @battle = Battle.all
  end

  def new
    @battle = Battle.new
  end

  def show
    @battle = Battle.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @battle = Battle.new(battle_params)
    if @battle.save
      redirect_to @battle
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

    private

    def battle_params
      params.require(:battle).permit(:name, :date, :location, :belligerentA, :belligerentB, :strengthA, :strengthB, :casualtiesA, :casualtiesB, :result)
    end
end
```

When I view the page source, I cannot find any child-title `h1` and `li`:

[image: page source of show.html.erb]

And Here is model:

```
class Battle < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessor :name, :date, :location, :belligerentA, :belligerentB, :strengthA, :strengthB, :casualtiesA, :casualtiesB, :result
  before_save { self.name = name.downcase }
  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :date,  presence: true
  validates :location,  presence: true
  validates :belligerentA,  presence: true
  validates :belligerentB,  presence: true
  validates :result,  presence: true
end
```

Here is my `rake routes` result:

```
    battles GET    /battles(.:format)          battles#index
            POST   /battles(.:format)          battles#create
 new_battle GET    /battles/new(.:format)      battles#new
edit_battle GET    /battles/:id/edit(.:format) battles#edit
     battle GET    /battles/:id(.:format)      battles#show
            PATCH  /battles/:id(.:format)      battles#update
            PUT    /battles/:id(.:format)      battles#update
            DELETE /battles/:id(.:format)      battles#destroy
       root GET    /                           pages#home
    contact GET    /contact(.:format)          pages#contact
      about GET    /about(.:format)            pages#about
```

And my new.html.erb:

```
<% provide(:title, 'Adding New Article') %>
<h1>Adding New Article</h1>

<div class="">
  <div class="">
    <%= form_for(@battle) do |f| %>
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>
      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>

      <%= f.label :date %>
      <%= f.text_field :date %>

      <%= f.label :location %>
      <%= f.text_field :location %>

      <%= f.label :belligerentA, 'Belligerent-A' %>
      <%= f.text_field :belligerentA %>
      VS
      <%= f.label :belligerentB, 'Belligerent-B' %>
      <%= f.text_field :belligerentB %>

      <%= f.label :strengthA, 'Strength-A' %>
      <%= f.text_field :strengthA %>
      VS
      <%= f.label :strengthB, 'Strength-B' %>
      <%= f.text_field :strengthB %>

      <%= f.label :casualtiesA, 'Casualties & Losses-A' %>
      <%= f.text_field :casualtiesA %>
      VS
      <%= f.label :casualtiesA, 'Casualties & Losses-B' %>
      <%= f.text_field :casualtiesB %>

      <%= f.label :result %>
      <%= f.text_field :result %>

      <%= f.submit "Create New Article" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Could someone figure out what's going on?

Comment: looks like your `@battle` record is completely empty.

Comment: From the looks of it you aren't saving the attributes of your `@battle` properly and it's saving an empty record. Could you post your controller actions?

Comment: After type in some data still got this same blank section at all.

Comment: K, i ll update my controller just a moment.

Comment: What happens in your logs when you put logger.info @battle in your controller after `@battle = Battle.new(battle_params)`?

Comment: please include your battle model also. Any validations in there that are not being met?

Comment: OK i ll include my model. sorry been to lunch.

Comment: Last missing parts are a) your form to create a battle from '/app/views/battles/new.html.erb' and b) routes for battle from routes.rb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theres your problem - all the `attr_accessor`s in the your Battle model.

Rails already provides those for you within ActiveRecord, and you've overwritten them, so your values won't be getting saved properly.

Remove them and all should be good.

Comment: Cheers pal, it helps. EVERY DETAIL.